# Pseudorandomness based on homomorphic multiplication property of Paillier cryptosystem

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, paillier

Given the instance $(n, g, \lambda)$ of Paillier cryptosystem with $\text{ord}(g) = n \lambda$ (symbols have their usual meaning), and $c = g^{na}$, is it possible to distinguish (computationally) $c' = g^{nab}$ from a random element in $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$, where $b \in_{R} \mathbb{Z}_{n\lambda}$?
I believe that given $g^{na}$ and $g^{nab}$, it is hard to find $b$ because that would imply security considerations against the homomorphic multiplication property of the Paillier scheme. Does the above mentioned pseudorandomness property also hold?

Could this property depend on the kind of primes chosen in $n = p \cdot q$?